# how to make Xcode indentation from beginning of previous line?

Tags: xcode, indentation

ok, possibly insanely n00b question or something i have overlooked in Xcode prefs: On pressing return, in stead of Xcode's syntax-aware indentation doing smart indent from whatever brackets  i've used on the previous line, how can I make it so Xcode indents just from the *beginning* of the previous line?
From the picture below, first block of code is what i got, second block of code is what I want.

Visual representation:
[visual representation http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/289/screenshot20100504at122.png](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/289/screenshot20100504at122.png)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to xcodes formatting, you can use [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/). It can understand Objective as well as a variety of other languages. I set mine up as a script in xcode and assigned it a hot key so that it reformats the whole file or just the selected code.